# Why should i add `/static/` before path to static file, django

Tags: python, django, static

My problem: static does not work if I use this:

```
<link href="{% static "css/style.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

And work perfectly if I add `/static/` before path:

```
<link href="{% static "static/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

My static settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('static', 'static'),
)
```

I think, it is not necessary to add it every time. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've specifically added a prefix, by using a tuple in your STATICFILES_DIRS setting - see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#prefixes-optional). Don't do that if you don't want one.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'static',
)
```